# How can I create an unclickable dynamic node in my MVC sitemap?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, mvcsitemapprovider

I'm using `MvcSiteMapProvider` to create breadcrumbs in my ASP.NET MVC application. I have some dynamic resources which I want to create some child nodes for. Some of these nodes, I want to appear in breadcrumbs but not be clickable.

For a static resource, you can specify `clickable="false"` in the XML sitemap document and these nodes will appear, but will not be hyperlinks. I can't find an equivalent property to set on the `DynamicNode` returned by my dynamic node provider class.

Is it possible to add a dynamic, "unclickable" node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DynamicNode` doesn't have n `Clickable` property, because it does not inherit from the `MvcSiteMapNode` class.

Reflecting on `MvcSiteMapNode` shows that the implementation of `Clickable` is backed by the [`Attributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sitemapnode.attributes.aspx) property:

```
public bool Clickable
{
    get
    {
        return ((this["clickable"] == null) || bool.Parse(this["clickable"]));
    }
    set
    {
        this["clickable"] = value.ToString();
    }
}
```

The `DynamicNode` class exposes its own `Attributes` property, which is copied to the `MvcSiteMapNode` instance when the dynamic nodes are parsed. The property can therefore be set using this code:

```
var node = new DynamicNode();

node.Attributes["clickable"] = "false";
```

Answer (score 1):

In v4 there is now a Clickable property on the dynamic node, and setting an attribute to clickable will now cause an error, because the properties are no longer backed by the Attributes dictionary.

```
var node = new DynamicNode();

node.Clickable = false;
```